# Counting occurrences of an id in a database table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm having some trouble with an Oracle database query and the related subqueries. At it's core, the problem is count the number of times an ID from one table occurs in another table.

**The Problem:**
I have two tables, an orders table, which stores information on ordered items from a web service. Data from that table is run through a process (which I have no control over) and the result is placed into a fulfilled table.

Order numbers are **not** unique to one item. Each order can have a large number of items, and each item is stored on a *line*. Items, however, can actually be a combo/package and that is what the process handles. An item, GAME_PACK for example, can come into the orders table and out on the other end comes out GAME1, GAME2, GAME3 and are associated by the order number.

[image: Simple diagram representing the order process]

The problem is, occasionally these items don't come out of the process correctly and then a line_item may not be associated with a fulfilled item. The only way I can, with the resources available, determine if there is an issue is by getting the maximum line_number and comparing that to the number of fulfilled_item groups.

**What I've tried:**
At first I thought it would be fairly simple to do, simply using a `rownumber()` or `denserank()` analytical function over a partition by the order number, but it has become much more confusing than that.
This is currently the query I am working with:

```
select * 
from(
    select max (item_index) over (partition by tbl.item_number) item_count, tbl.*
        from (
            select i.item_fulfill_number, i.order_number, row_number()over(partition by i.item_number, i.order_number order by i.order_number) item_index 
            from fulfilled_items i ) tbl
            ) results 
            inner join (
                select * 
                from (
                    select orderinfo.order_number as order_order_number, orderinfo.line_number, orderinfo.ordered_item, row_number() over(partition by orderinfo.order_number order by orderinfo.line_number desc) order_row 
                    from orderinfo
                    ) 
                where order_row <= 1
                )
            on results.order_number = order_order_number
where results.item_count = results.item_index and ordered_item like 'GAME%'
```

*note that right now I am pulling when the counts match, this logic will be reversed when I am certain the query works*

**Constraints**

- I do **not** have access to the process that splits the items
- The query should run quickly, we are working with upwards of 50,000
  possible records
- *The query was tested at 22 seconds to over 2 minutes execution time*
- Pagination is going to be used, if you answer, don't worry about
  including it, but it is something to consider because it can greatly
  help or hurt the speed of the query
- I cannot touch table structure

**Table Structure and Graphic Representation**
[image: The relation between the orders table and the fulfilled items table after the process has run] (Maximum line number represents the number of fulfilled_item groups)

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

**EDIT**
Results should look something like this:
[image: a sample output for the query]

where item comes from the orders table, and result is OK, BAD based on whether or not the fulfilled groups matches the max line number.

Comment: seeing what the final result should look like would be helpful

Comment: @JamieD77 Added a quick sample output. I'll provide a better one within the hour

Comment: what would Fulfilled table row `123  |  444` represent?  that would give you 4 groups with only 3 line numbers.

Comment: honestly with there not appearing to be a link between `Ordered_Item` and `Item_FulFill_Number` getting the right answer won't be 100% since you're also filtering the `Ordered_Item` by `like 'GAME%'` and you can't apply same filter to `Item_FulFill_Number`

Comment: @JamieD77 the additional 444 was a mistake, good catch. As for the link between the two, an order that does not have GAME will not show in the second order fulfillment table.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, each order should have the same number of fulfillment groups as there are line numbers in the order.  Each fulfillment group will be of unknown size and be represented by a unique fulfillment number.  Based on that, I think the query should be as simple as this:

```
SELECT 
  main.*, 
  'BAD' AS result
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      o.order_number,
      COUNT(o.line_number) OVER (PARTITION BY o.order_number) AS order_lines,
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item_fulfill_number) FROM fulfilled_items f WHERE f.order_number = o.order_number) AS fulfilled_groups
    FROM orders o
) main
WHERE order_lines != fulfilled_groups
```

The subquery counts the number of lines (just in case a line number gets skipped, but you could change this back to a max on the line number if you really want to) and the number of distinct fulfillment groups.  The overall query returns those orders where the two counts are not equal.

Comment: The only concern I have would be the running time of the query. A coworker suggested a similar solution using distinct, so I will give this a shot. Database is currently down so I'll post back with an update when I give it a shot

Comment: Unfortunately this query runs slower than what I posted in the original question and I was forced to kill it at 8 minutes in. As of right now, the cancel is still pending. Waiting on a call from the DBA lol. Thanks for giving it a shot though, I appreciate the assistance